# Powershell Install-WindowsFeature Application-Server (and subfeatures) and assign certificate

Tags: powershell, ssl-certificate, windows-server-2012-r2

I want to use a Powershell script to install Application Server on a windows 2012 server. When using the wizard, it prompts for you to select a certificate (for WS-Atomic Transactions) from the local machine store (or generate a self-signed one, or assign one later). Can I specify a certificate when running something similar to the following?

```
Install-WindowsFeature -Name Application-Server -IncludeAllSubFeature -IncludeManagementTools -ComputerName $svrName -Credential $credential
```

Or is there a powershell script to associate a cert after the fact?

If I'm already binding a SSL certificate to the default web site in IIS for https, do I even need to associate the cert with WS-AT?

Note: I'm generating certs with the Get-Certificate cmdlet, so getting hold of the cert isn't a problem:

```
$x = Get-Certificate etc...
$cert = $x.Certificate
```